# If the fractional part of the number $\dfrac{2^{403}}{15}$ is $\dfrac{k}{15}$, then $k$ is equal to

Tags: binomial-coefficients, solution-verification, binomial-theorem

If the fractional part of the number $\dfrac{2^{403}}{15}$ is $\dfrac{k}{15}$, then  $k$ is equal to

My attempt is as follows:-

$$\dfrac{2^{13}\cdot 2^{390}}{15}$$
$$2^{13}\cdot\dfrac{\displaystyle{390\choose 0}+\displaystyle{390\choose 1}+\displaystyle{390\choose 2}+\displaystyle{390\choose 3}+\cdots\cdots+\displaystyle{390\choose 390}}{15}$$

As $390$ is divisible by $15$, so fractional part would come from $\displaystyle{390\choose 0},\displaystyle{390\choose 390}$, hence fractional part would be fractional part of $\dfrac{2^{13}\cdot2}{15}$

$$\dfrac{2^{14}}{15}=\dfrac{16384}{15}=1092+\dfrac{4}{15}$$

Hence fractional part should be $\dfrac{4}{15}$ and $k$ should be $4$ but answer is $8$. What am I missing here. I tried to find my mistake but didn't get any breakthrough.

Comment: Hint: $390\choose 3$ is not divisible by 15.

Comment: If $2^4\equiv 1\bmod 15$, then $2^{400}=(2^4)^{100}\equiv ?$ and then $2^{403}=2^{400}×2^3\equiv ?$.  Can you fill in?

Comment: If you're not familiar with $\mod 15$ then since $2^4=15+1$ by binomial theorem $2^{400} =(15+1)^{100} $

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2^4 = 16 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$. So:

$$
2^{403} 
  =      2^{400} \cdot 2^3 
  =      (2^4)^{100} \cdot 2^3
  \equiv 1^{100} \cdot 8
  \equiv 8 \pmod{15}
$$